# Pandas DataFrame to html with JavaScript code gives error

Tags: javascript, pandas

I'm trying to save Pandas DataFrame to html file with embedded JavaScript code for autorefreshing.

My code is:

```
import pandas as pd

html_string = """
<html>
  <head>
<script>
function timedRefresh(timeoutPeriod) 
{
  setTimeout("location.reload(true);",timeoutPeriod);
}
window.onload = timedRefresh(5000);

</script>

</head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="df_style.css"/>
  <body>
    {table}
  </body>
</html>
"""


df1.to_html("/html/calls.html")
    with open('/html/calls.html', 'w') as f:
       f.write(html_string.format(table=df1.to_html(classes='mystyle')))
```

But i get error:

```
KeyError: 'setTimeout("location'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to escape the curly brackets of the JS function. Use double brackets `{{}}`

**Ex:**

```
html_string = """
<html>
  <head>
<script>
function timedRefresh(timeoutPeriod) 
{{
  setTimeout("location.reload(true);",timeoutPeriod);
}}
window.onload = timedRefresh(5000);

</script>

</head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="df_style.css"/>
  <body>
    {table}
  </body>
</html>
"""
```